# Dynamically update/combine two data.frames in R

Tags: r, vector, merge, dataframe

I haven't found a solution on the web because it is not easy to come up with the right question of the problem.
I have two data.frames, x and y, and want to combine them to get z:

The tricky thing is that z compares the date value of x and y, and takes the most recent observations to update A, B, C and D. Hence "dynamically" update/combine.

```
x=data.frame(c("2000-01-01","2000-06-01","2001-01-01"),c("100","100","100"),c("200","200","200"))
colnames(x)=c("Date","A","B")

y=data.frame(c("2000-01-05","2000-04-09"),c("10","0"),c("0","35"))
colnames(y)=c("Date","C","D")

z=data.frame(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-05","2000-04-09","2000-06-01","2001-01-01"),c("100","100","100","100","100"),c("200","200","200","200","200"),c("0","10","10","0","0"),c("0","0","35","0","0"))
colnames(z)=c("Date","A","B","C","D")

x$Date = as.Date(x$Date)
y$Date = as.Date(y$Date)
```

Question: How to get to `z` by an efficient code?

To illustrate:

```
> x
        Date   A   B
1 2000-01-01 100 200
2 2000-06-01 100 200
3 2001-01-01 100 200
> y
        Date  C  D
1 2000-01-05 10  0
2 2000-04-09  0 35
> z
        Date   A   B  C  D
1 2000-01-01 100 200  0  0
2 2000-01-05 100 200 10  0
3 2000-04-09 100 200 10 35
4 2000-06-01 100 200 10 35
5 2001-01-01 100 200 10 35
>
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers below.
The solutions seems to be a simple full join followed by a loop in a loop (I figured out the second step):

```
x$Date = as.Date(x$Date)
y$Date = as.Date(y$Date)

tt=merge(x,y,by='Date',all=TRUE)

for (i in 2:(ncol(x)+ncol(y)-1)){
  for (j in 2:(nrow(x)+nrow(y))){
    if (is.na(tt[j,i])==TRUE & is.na(tt[j-1,i])==FALSE){
      tt[j,i]=tt[j-1,i]}
  }
}
```

EDIT2: The solutions posted by others further below seem to be more efficient. Just for completeness, my longer solutions works if the 0 in y are replaced by NA, i.e. defining y as :

```
y=data.frame(c("2000-01-05","2000-04-09"),c("10",NA),c(NA,"35"))
colnames(y)=c("Date","C","D")
```

and then replacing the NAs in z in a final step.

I learnt from my first EDIT and I am not editing the original problem above to avoid confusion.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You may need to convert the 'Date' columns to 'Date' class. i.e `x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date)`, similarly for the y.  `df1 <- merge(x, y, by='Date', all=TRUE);df2 <- df1[order(df1$Date),]; library(zoo);df2[2:3] <- lapply(df2[2:3], na.locf)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Quite close, but does not work yet as the element z[3,4] is still NA and not 10. Setting df2[2:3] to df2[2:5] does not work. Any idea?

Comment: `df2[4:5][is.na(df2[4:5])] <- 0` would set it to 0

Comment: You're for loop could probably be avoided

Comment: @akrun you want to post some reasonable solution maybe?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Looks like the OP updated the expected output.  Do you have a solution for it?  My solution was based on the first version.  If so, you can post it.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the code you provided in your edit.

Comment: With the edit code, avoiding the for for loops could be done with `tt <- na.locf(tt)`  and eventually replacing nas by 0 with `tt[is.na(tt)] <- 0` after this

Comment: The one I don't get with the multiple edit is this line `3 2000-04-09 100 200 10 35` why is the 0 becoming 10 ???

Comment: @Tensibai: The third line in z stems from the second line in y: [code]2 2000-04-09  0 35

Comment: @fuji2015 I understood from where it comes. My question was: WHY should it be transformed to 10 35 and not stay at 0 35 ??? It's not unknow, it's known and 0... (Your code output and expected output does not match, that's hard to understand what you really want at end...)

Comment: @Tensibai: Got your point. Sorry for the confusion: I was presenting a mini-example of a larger problem. The matrix x has in reality some stock portfolio composition (number of shares). The matrix y tells us that there is a share added. In this case shares C or D. However, matrix y "does not know" which shares have already been added. This is why you have a 0 instead of a 10. The 0 is then replaced in the final output z by 10.

Comment: In this case consider accepting @Jaap answer which match your desired output avoiding the for loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be using a combination of the `data.table` and the `na.locf` function from the `zoo` packackages:

```
# loading the needed packages
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# converting x & y to datatables
setDT(x)
setDT(y)

# merge x & y into z
z <- merge(x, y, by="Date", all=TRUE) # this works in base R as well

# fill the NA's with the last observation
cols <- c("A","B","C","D") # in this specific case, you can also use: LETTERS[1:4]
z[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, rule = 1, na.rm=FALSE), .SDcols= cols]
```

this gives:

```
> z
         Date   A   B  C  D
1: 2000-01-01 100 200 NA NA
2: 2000-01-05 100 200 10  0
3: 2000-04-09 100 200  0 35
4: 2000-06-01 100 200  0 35
5: 2001-01-01 100 200  0 35
```

This result can also be achieved in base R as mentioned by @Tensibai in the comments (which for some reason didn't work on my system at first):

```
z <- merge(x, y, by="Date", all=TRUE)
z <- na.locf(z)
```

---

To get the exact desired output, you will need some additional steps (omitting the first steps as they are the same):

```
# merge x & y into z
z <- merge(x, y, by="Date", all=TRUE) # this works in base R as well

# replace the zero with NA
z[z==0] <- NA

# fill the NA's with the last observation
cols <- LETTERS[1:4]
z[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, rule = 1, na.rm=FALSE), .SDcols= cols]

# replace the remaining NA's with zero's
z[is.na(z)] <- 0
```

this gives:

```
> z
         Date   A   B  C  D
1: 2000-01-01 100 200  0  0
2: 2000-01-05 100 200 10  0
3: 2000-04-09 100 200 10 35
4: 2000-06-01 100 200 10 35
5: 2001-01-01 100 200 10 35
```

In base R you would do:

```
z <- merge(x, y, by="Date", all=TRUE)
z[z==0] <- NA
z <- na.locf(z)
z[is.na(z)] <- 0
```

to get the same result.

Comment: I think you could just shorten this to `z <- merge(setDT(x), setDT(y), by="Date", all=TRUE);
cols <- LETTERS[1:4];
z[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, rule = 1, na.rm=FALSE), .SDcols= cols]`, Also not sure if you need `rule = 1` here

Comment: Don't update per his desired output, as he changed it in his edit. I think its better to update the desired output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using dplyr and some functions:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# dataset
x=data.frame(c("2000-01-01","2000-06-01","2001-01-01"),
             c("100","100","100"),
             c("200","200","200"), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(x)=c("Date","A","B")

y=data.frame(c("2000-01-05","2000-04-09"),
             c("10","0"),
             c("0","35"), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(y)=c("Date","C","D")

# update date columns
x$Date = ymd(x$Date)
y$Date = ymd(y$Date)

# function that replaces NAs with 0s
ff = function(x){x[is.na(x)]=0 
                 return(as.numeric(x))}

# function that updates zero elements with the previous ones
ff2 = function(x){

  for (i in 2:length(x)){x[i] = ifelse(x[i]==0, x[i-1], x[i])}

  return(x)

}

# create the full dataset
xy =
    x %>% 
    full_join(y, by="Date") %>% 
    arrange(Date)

xy

#         Date    A    B    C    D
# 1 2000-01-01  100  200 <NA> <NA>
# 2 2000-01-05 <NA> <NA>   10    0
# 3 2000-04-09 <NA> <NA>    0   35
# 4 2000-06-01  100  200 <NA> <NA>
# 5 2001-01-01  100  200 <NA> <NA>


  xy %>%
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(ff)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-Date) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ff2)) %>%
  bind_cols(data.frame(Date=xy$Date)) %>%
  select(Date,A,B,C,D)

#           Date   A   B  C  D
#   1 2000-01-01 100 200  0  0
#   2 2000-01-05 100 200 10  0
#   3 2000-04-09 100 200 10 35
#   4 2000-06-01 100 200 10 35
#   5 2001-01-01 100 200 10 35
```